# Nuget updates packages during build even when configured to not

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package-restore

In

> tools->options->Nuget Package Manager->General

I have configured nuget like this:

```
[ ] Allow NuGet to download missing packages
  [ ] Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio
```

When I build my project, I get messages like this:

```
33>  Restoring NuGet packages...
33>  To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
33>  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
```

But I unchecked that option, so why do I get those messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your project is using the older now deprecated NuGet package restore that is MSBuild based and runs NuGet.exe on every build. These messages are from NuGet.exe.

To prevent this from happening you should be able to set RestorePackages to false in each project file but NuGet seems to like to keep setting this back to true for some reason.

```
 <RestorePackages>false</RestorePackages>
```

Another way would be to not use the MSBuild based NuGet package restore and remove it. Then if you build within Visual Studio, and are using a recent version of the NuGet package manager, the NuGet packages will be automatically restored by Visual Studio just before the build.

Comment: How would you "not use the MsBuild bases NuGet" approach?

Comment: There is a section in the nuget.org documentation about migrating - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#migrating-to-automatic-restore