# xamarin git pull nuget package error

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

I am new in Xamarin android development.

I take the code pull from git.

After that i opened my solution in visual studio.

I cleaned the solution - now it is fine.

then i trying to build the solution it is showing the error.

```
>Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
NuGet Package restore failed for project app: Unable to find version '2.0.0' of package 'FastAndroidCamera'.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'FastAndroidCamera.2.0.0' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: app, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>D:\PRANAV\TOLL\GIT\MobileApp-12-06-2018\MobileApp\app\app.csproj(467,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.3\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.props.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========\
```

This is the error that i am getting . So guys can you figure where i am doing the mistakes ?

Comment: It looks like NuGet is unable to resolve api.nuget.org. Have you tried restarting Visual Studio and are you able to access https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json?

Comment: done but same error\ is there

Comment: I tried to restore the nuget but same issue..

Comment: And to double check, is the computer that is running Visual Studio connected to the internet and able to access https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json?

Comment: i tried to run this on browser im getting one json

Comment: internet is connected and working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message,

> To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual
> Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck
> 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'

It seems the project use the older now deprecated NuGet package restore that is MSBuild based and runs `NuGet.exe` on every build. These messages are from `NuGet.exe`.

Check the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180942/nuget-updates-packages-during-build-even-when-configured-to-not).

To resolve this issue, you should make sure to upgrade to the latest version of NuGet which does package restore automatically instead of MSBuild based NuGet package restore.

You're going to want to delete the NuGet targets (delete the `.nuget` folder and then manually edit your `.csproj` files and remove the lines that import the `NuGet.targets` file). This is no longer needed. Using the new way to restore nuget package, the NuGet packages will be automatically restored by Visual Studio just before the build.

See this post by David Ebbo for more information: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html and the blog [how to switch from "Enable Package Restore" to "Automatic Package Restore"](https://chrismay.org/2015/01/07/nuget-switching-from-enable-package-restore-to-automatic-package-restore/)

Hope this helps.